# How to access $_POST in Twig form?

Tags: php, post, twig

I'm trying to print the value of the input field 'gameTitle' in Twig.

This is my code:

```
<h1>New game</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Game Title</label>  
    <input type="text" value="Monopoly" name="gameTitle"><br>
    <input class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add game">
</form>
{% if app.request.post('submit') %}
    {{ app.request('gameTitle')}}
{% endif %}
```

I've also tried:

```
{{ app.request.parameter.post('gameTitle}
```

As a result I want to print this result: "gameTitle is Monopoly".

**My question**, how do I do the following PHP code in Twig?

```
<?php
echo "gameTitle is ".$_POST['gameTitle'];
?>
```

**Update:**
- I'm not using Symfony, just Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/
This does not work for me:

```
{{app.request.post('gameTitle')}}
{{app.request.request.get('gameTitle')}}
{{ app.request.request.get("gameTitle") }}
gameTitle is {{ app.request.request.post('gameTitle') }}
```

Comment: try `app.request.post('gameTitle')`?

Comment: Or `app.request.request.get('gameTitle')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, the vanilla Twig doesn't provide access to the request [variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables) by default. You should pass them to the template explicitly, e.g.:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => __DIR__ . '/tpl_cache',
));

echo $twig->render('template.twig', ['post' => $_POST]);
```

Then use it as follows:

```
{% if post.gameTitle is defined %}
Game title: {{ post.gameTitle }}
{% endif%}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
{{ app.request.request.get("gameTitle") }}
```

It has been changed.

Comment: Hi, could you provide source for this?

Comment: The year is 2024, and this should be marked as the answer now. For anyone looking for the source documentation for this answer, you can refer to Symfony's official docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/templates.html#the-app-global-variable